# Order by on length of the string and then by single alphabet desc in pl sql

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a set of single letters and double letters that needs to be ordered.

```
Data : 
A
B
D
E
F
G
AL
BL
DL

Output :
AL
BL
DL
E
F
G
A
B
D
```

I can achieve the following result by query

```
SELECT column_name
        FROM table_name
   ORDER BY LENGTH(column_name) desc, column_name asc;

AL
BL
DL
A
B
D
E
F
G
```

but how to place A B D after E F G

Any help will be appriciated...

Comment: What do you want those particular letters later?

Comment: Expected O/P is in the ques. @GordonLinoff

Comment: yes, I want A B D in the last but 2 letters should come first then everything except A B D and then A B D in the last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use additional information on the maximum length based on the first character in the string.  So, `'A'` would have a value of 2 and `'G'` would have a value of 1:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM (select t.*,
             max(length(column_name)) over (partition by substr(column_name, 1, 1)) as fclen
      from table_name t
     ) t
ORDER BY LENGTH(column_name) desc,
         (case when fclen = 1 then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         column_name asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name
 FROM table_name
 ORDER BY 
    LEN(column_name),column_name;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).